# bootstrap template 3 for two screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to have a system on two screens, I have two div "col-lg-6" each using a screen and that by shrinking the screen to 1, the second div becomes a right side floating. Some idea occurs to them. Thank you.

Comment: You already answered your own question. Using `.col-lg-6` will split the window in half. If you stretch that window to fit 2 screens, each col will be on a screen (if the screens are equal width and are set to the same resolution, that is...), when you shrink the window again, the window will still be divided in 2 columns.

Comment: I'm sure about that, the theme is to be able to recognize when it goes from 2 screens to 1 and the other col-lg-6 becomes a sidebar menu